# web scraping directors sections IMDB in r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** data from IMDB website https://www.imdb.com/list/ls041125816/ , I'm trying to get the directors names with this command : html_nodes("p.text-mutated + a") and also tried html_nodes(".text-mutated + p a") but both are not working

note that this is my first time doing web-scraping

Your help will be much appreciated

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector is not matching anything. This code gets you the directors:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls041125816/"

webpage <- read_html(url)

directors_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,".text-small:nth-child(6)")

directors_data <- html_text(directors_data_html)

directors <- directors_data %>% 
             str_split("\\|") %>% 
             map(., 1) %>% 
             unlist()


directors %>% 
  tibble("directors" = .) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(directors,"Director"))
```